# Replace non blank row values with the column name

Tags: excel

[image: My non-blank example]

My example: Replace non blank row values with the column name and place the end results in a separate table as shown in the image or in a separate sheet

I have 100 columns and 5000 rows of data so either Marco or Excel-Formula is fine .

Comment: [Okay](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you tried?

Comment: =INDEX(C:C,SMALL(ROW($C$3:$F$3)+(100*($C$3:$C$3="")), 1))&"" this is working for specific columns but does not work for columns and the format that i am looking for.. sorry to say that i am very new to excel..

Answer (score 0):

Enter the formula shown in the specified cell.  Then fill down and across:

[image]

Comment: this is not working on excel, the reason could be EMP_Name is auto resulting as Ravi and source to error value.. i am using Mac

Comment: @user7359795 obviously works in Excel. See screenshot. What means *auto resulting*? Didn't you define those terms? If you didn't, what did you expect to happen?

Comment: yes i did define those two terms as in the screen shot. when i execute the query I do not see any result.

Comment: @user7359795 upload your workbook showing problem to some file sharing site and post link.

Comment: @user7359795  Again, exactly what do you mean by *auto resulting* and also what do you mean by *source to error value*?

Comment: @ Ron Rosenfeld added the screen shot as you asked me, issue 1::  I don't see any result. Issue 2:: after defining EMP_Name, Source terms they are throwing Value errors. Please have a look at screen shot.

Comment: one more question is, if i have 2000 columns and 5000 rows will this formula works?

Comment: @user7359795 If you did things as intended it should work, since it works here. That is why I asked you to ***upload your workbook showing problem to some file sharing site and post link.***

Comment: @user7359795 I see you have now increased the size of your worksheet from `100x5000` as in your post, to `2000*5000` in your last comment.  I don't know if it will work.  You will need to get it to work on a small sample, and then see if it works on the larger sample.  If it doesn't work, you may need 64-bit Excel or another tool.

Comment: 100*5000 that is also fine since I see the number 3456 in your solution I thought it would work only for those four columns.

Comment: @user7359795 Once you have it working for four columns, it is trivial to extend it.

Comment: i am able to resolve the issue using replace every cell with its header and remove the empty cells of the table with search.. thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

Source, Target does not have any importance here, I mentioned them for understanding. And looks like 2 @A17  was added by mistake.

Comment: This is not an answer to your question.  As the original poster, add clarifications by editing your original question, or, if appropriate, in the comments.